# Problem regarding coloring balls drawn from a bin

Tags: probability, expected-value, recreational-mathematics, balls-in-bins, coupon-collector

I'm not sure if this has been asked before, but here I have the following problem:

> There are $n$ indistinguishable red balls in a bin. Each "round," $k$ balls are randomly chosen from the bin with equal probability. All $k$ balls are colored blue and put back into the bin (this means that balls that are already blue are not changed). What is the expected number of rounds needed to color all $n$ balls blue?

Is there an explicit formula for this problem? I've thought about this problem for a bit and quickly got stumped, but I realized that unless there was some insight for the problem, a recursive formula of some sort is probably needed as each round relies on the results of the previous rounds.  If the formula turns out to be recursive, is there some relatively "simple" heuristic that can estimate the expected number of rounds?

There's also the tricky case of infinitely drawing blue balls after initially drawing some red balls, which would result in an infinite number of rounds. But my gut feeling says that the probability of this happening are small enough that the expected number of rounds should be finite.

After searching a bit online, this seems to be (correct me if I'm wrong) the [Coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) but multiple coupons are drawn at once  instead of just one at a time, and that each of the coupons drawn are all distinct.  If that's the case, can any of the insights from that problem be used in the problem I have currently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be calculated as

$${\bf e_1}^T \left(I_n - \left({\frac{ {{n-i \choose j-i}} {i \choose k-j+i} }{n\choose k}} \right)_{i=0,j=0}^{n-1} \right)^{-1} {\bf 1}$$

Here $I_n$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix, $\bf e_1$ is the first standard basis vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and ${\bf1}$ is the $n$-vector of all ones. Notice that the product with the vectors actually just calculates the sum of the first row of the matrix, and also that $i$ and $j$ go from $0$ to $n-1$.

We get the following values for $n=1\dots 10$ (listed for values of $k=1\dots n$):

```
n =  1 :  [1]
n =  2 :  [3, 1]
n =  3 :  [11/2, 5/2, 1]
n =  4 :  [25/3, 19/5, 7/3, 1]
n =  5 :  [137/12, 671/126, 29/9, 9/4, 1]
n =  6 :  [147/10, 97/14, 327/76, 41/14, 11/5, 1]
n =  7 :  [363/20, 5693/660, 85691/15810, 257/68, 11/4, 13/6, 1]
n =  8 :  [761/35, 1003423/96525, 974651/148005, 45949/9867, 951/275, 71/27, 15/7, 1]
n =  9 :  [7129/280, 122429/10010, 3352087/429940, 161699429/29100500, 524/125, 5915/1826, 89/35, 17/8, 1]
n =  10 :  [7381/252, 961349/68068, 8241679/911064, 1445423/222794, 3909721/792407, 916379/236379, 733/238, 109/44, 19/9, 1]
```

Answer (score 5):

You already have an excellent solution, but here is a solution by a different method that renders the result in a different form.

Define $T$ to be the number of the first draw on which all red balls have been seen; we want to find $E(T)$. We will use the theorem that
$$E(T) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} P(T > m)$$
Now $T>m$ if and only if at least one ball has never been seen in draws one through $m$; by inclusion/exclusion, this probability is
$$P(T > m) = \sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{j+1} \binom{n}{j} \frac{\binom{n-j}{k}^m}{\binom{n}{k}^m}$$
So $$E(T) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} P(T > m) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{j+1} \binom{n}{j} \frac{\binom{n-j}{k}^m}{\binom{n}{k}^m}$$
Switching the order of summation,
$$\begin{align}
E(T) &= \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{j+1} \binom{n}{j} \frac{\binom{n-j}{k}^m}{\binom{n}{k}^m} \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{j+1} \binom{n}{j} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{\binom{n-j}{k}^m}{\binom{n}{k}^m} \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{j+1} \binom{n}{j} \frac{1}{1-\binom{n-j}{k}/\binom{n}{k}}
\end{align}$$
In the last step we summed a geometric series.

Comment: Nice answer! How did you even think of this? Also this seems very different from the other answer, yet they both do the same thing. Something about that is amazing to me.

Comment: Wow, this is nicer formula since you don't have to invert a matrix :D (Well, only need the first row of the inverse matrix, but anyway.) There is similarity to the matrix method, since $(I-Q)^{-1} = I+Q+Q^2+\dots$ but that the geometric series can be summed, that's a nice addition. Or actually, seeing (with PIE) that the first row elements of $Q^m$ have that form $(-1)^{j+1} \binom{n}{j} \frac{\binom{n-j}{k}^m}{\binom{n}{k}^m}$.

Comment: @AidenChow The answer I gave is actually a standard result for the Coupon Collector's Problem with coupons coming in groups. I looked around and couldn't find a derivation on stackexchange so I wrote this one, but it's likely there is a derivation somewhere and I just didn't find it. I agree it's hard to see the connection between the inclusion/exclusion method and the matrix method--a fact which is interesting in its own right.

Answer (score 1):

For $n = 3$ and $k = 1$ ... the story unfolds thus ...

Round 1: 1 red ball, colored blue, put back in the bag

Round 2: Say you did pick a red ball. You color it blue and put it back in the bin.

Round 3: Say you picked the last red ball (you have the Devil's luck). You color it blue and ... we're done!

That is, the *minimum* number of *rounds* = $3$, for $n = 3$ and $k = 1$

What is the probability, call it P(C), of this happening?

$P(C) = 1 \times \frac{2}{3} \times \frac{1}{3} = \frac{2}{9}$

The *maximum* number of rounds would correspond to the following probabilities:

1. $1 \times \frac{1}{3} \times \frac{1}{3} \times ...$   (picking the same ball colored blue every round after the first)
2. $1 \times \frac{2}{3} \times \frac{2}{3} \times ...$ (picking the same balls colored blue every round after the second)

---

From the above we can see that for $n$ balls, if we pick $k$ balls at a time (assuming you're insanely lucky),

Round 1, $k$ balls colored blue: $n - k$ balls left
Round 2, $k$ balls colored: $n - 2k$ balls left
Round $m$, Another $k$ balls colored: $n - mk$ balls left

The rounds end when $0$ balls are left
$n - mk = 0$
$mk = n $
$m= \frac{n}{k}$

The *minimum* number of rounds ($m$) = $\frac{n}{k}$. If the answer is a *mixed fraction*, round to the nearest, greater integer.

The probability of this happening = $1 \times \frac{n - k}{n} \times \frac{n - 2k}{n} \times ... \times \frac{n - (m - 1)k}{n}$

---

**EDIT 1 START**

For 3 balls ...

The probability of either of the 2 scenarios where you fail to color all the balls blue = $P(F)$

$P(F) = \left( 1 \times \frac{1}{3} \times \frac{1}{3} \times ...\right) + \left( 1 \times \frac{2}{3} \times \frac{2}{3} \times ... \right) = \left( \frac{1}{3} \right)^n + \left( \frac{2}{3}\right)^n$

Calculate $P(F)$ such that $P(F) \leq 5\%$ i.e. $\left( \frac{1}{3}\right)^n + \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n \leq 5\%$.

Then, the probability of success = $1 - P(F)$ (???)

Generalize for $n$ balls.
**EDIT 1 END**

---

**EDIT 2 START**

X = The number of rounds to color all the balls

$E(X) = p_1 \cdot x_1 + p_2 \cdot x_2 + ... + p_n \cdot x_n$

where $p_n$ is the probability that $x_n$ rounds are required to color all the balls.

I have calculated, for 3 balls ($n$ = 3), picking 1 ball at a time ($k$ = 1), the probability that 3 rounds will be required ($\frac{2}{9}$).

The probability that 4 rounds will be required = $1 \times \frac{1}{3} \times \frac{2}{3} \times \frac{1}{3} + 1 \times \frac{2}{3}  \times \frac{2}{3} \times \frac{1}{3} \times 2 = \frac{10}{27}$

Continuing along this trajectory, we can calculate the theoretical probability of increasing number of rounds that are required to color all the balls blue.  As $x_n$ increases, $p_n$ decreases (tends to $0$). We will have to make a call, so to speak, if you must have an *average* number of rounds. That is exactly what $95\%$  probability is all about.

$E(X) = \frac{2}{9} \cdot 3 + \frac{10}{27} \cdot 4 + ... + p_c \cdot x_c$

$x_c$ is the *critical number of rounds* needed for success such that $p_c$ is practically $0$. I have *chosen* $p_c = 0.05 = 5\%$ In other words, in our world, $5\% = 0\%$

Comment: So for some random numbers like $n=1256$ and $k=5$, can you walk through your strategy to give me a number? I’m not sure I fully understand your answer.

Comment: And can you explain why $P(F)$ has to be $\le5\%$?

Comment: @AidenChow, just following the herd. Statistical significance is pegged at $\geq 95\%$. probability. It's not written in stone though - you may be happy with 70% or even 99.9%

Comment: After reading your answer thoroughly, I get the impression that you don’t fully understand what expected value is… expected value in this case simply means that if I were to run a simulation of the scenario I described in the question for infinitely many times, how many rounds would it take on average to paint all balls blue? I’m not looking for the number of rounds in order for there to be a $95\%$ probability to paint all balls blue, I’m simply looking for the “average,” or the expected, value, so to speak.

Comment: @AidenChow, . Well, why would you look for the *expected value* if not to be *confident* about having colored all the balls? My answer (unfortunately off mark) gives you the number of rounds that corresponds to a high probability that one has colored all the balls.  Also, having found a max and min, average just pops out of that, no?

Comment: @AidenChow, did you try using Random Number Tables (simulation)?

Comment: I don’t feel to argue about what expected value means as it is a well established mathematical term. As for your second question, yes, I have just ran a simulation for my aforementioned example in an earlier comment, $n=1256$ and $k=5$, and the expected value should be around 1935.

Comment: To be precise about what expected value means, let’s say that there are $N$ events that have associated values $x_i$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,N$. Then the expected value is defined as $E(X)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^Nx_iP(x_i)$. Especially notice there is no mention of a confidence probability or anything like that. In this case, $x_i$ would be the number of rounds needed to paint all the balls blue while $P(x_i)$ is the probability of painting all balls blue with exactly $x_i$ rounds.